# Radio buttons change value from another class

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I have a class where i want to create 6 one time choice radio buttons, so I have created a radio button separate widget,   how can i call this widget and change the values of radio buttons. here is what i have done

Here is the separated widget which i want to call 6 times from another class :

```
  class ChooseTime extends StatefulWidget {
      final int value;
      final int selection;
      final int num;
      final String time;
      final Function selectTime;
      ChooseTime(
          {this.selection, this.value, this.num, this.time, this.selectTime});
      @override
      _ChooseTimeState createState() => _ChooseTimeState();
    }

 Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Radio(
                focusColor: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                groupValue: _selection,
                onChanged: widget.selectTime,
                value: widget.value,
              ),
              Text(
                widget.time,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: _selection == widget.num
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

And here is the Class where i am calling widget above :

```
  selectTime(int timeSelected) {
    setState(() {
      _selection = timeSelected;
    });
  }


          Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      ChooseTime(
                        selection: 1,
                        value: 1,
                        num: 1,
                        time: "09:00-11:00",
                        selectTime: selectTime,
                      ),
                      ChooseTime(
                        selection: 2,
                        value: 2,
                        num: 2,
                        time: "11:00-14:00",
                        selectTime: selectTime,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

I have tried the code above but when i press the button they are not changing.

Comment: Please add proper code for easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use Provider , bloc Pattern to manage your app state

Comment: how ? can you give an example please, i am new in flutter